# How many threads is created for java main method execution?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a java main method. I put the java main thread sleep for sometime.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread.sleep(10);
}
```

Total, how many number of threads would be created for java main execution (including deamon thread)

Comment: Any answer will be bound to a specific version of a specific JVM implementation (and perhaps even on a specific platform), plus runtime settings such as the kind of garbage collector.  You can have as little as 1 thread or as many threads as the JVM needs for its own requirements (e.g. parallel GC, I/O completion ports, or generally, any kind of low-level worker thread pool).

Comment: @acelent I suggest you make an Answer of your Comment.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly one.

You can check it by adding a line:

```
System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());
```

Sleeping a thread creates no new threads:

> sleep(long millis) Causes the currently executing thread to sleep
>   (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of
>   milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers
>   and schedulers.

Comment: Javadoc for `Thread.activeCount()` says, "Returns an estimate of the number of active threads in the current thread's thread group."  I don't know what that means exactly, but it does _not_ sound like the same thing as the number of live threads in the whole JVM.  When I compile and run a Java program that does nothing but call `Thread.sleep(1000000)` from main(), I get a process with twenty two threads on my Linux box.  A core dump shows that three of those are Java threads, and the rest are pure native threads.

Comment: @jameslarge Of course. But they are all service threads, directly unusable and even unnoticeable from your code. I have understood the questioner asks about threads that run his code.